# Checkout linux project to workspace on Windows

Tags: windows, perforce

I am using Perforce as a version control system. When I create a new project in Windows and say Get Latest from the Depot a project which was written on Linux and has Linux line endings seems to have Windows Line Endings when it was downloaded to Windows workspace. I do now know who is manipulating the line endings. The version control system itself , namely perforce, or the operating system Windows.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Perforce translates text files into the native format when writing them to a workspace.  This is because (for example) most Windows IDEs expect CRLF formatting whereas most Linux IDEs expect LF formatting.  Automatic conversion means you don't have to think about it.

If you want to manually set the line endings that a given workspace uses, change the `LineEnd` option in the client spec; the default `local` will simply match the standard format for the local platform, but you can specify `unix` if you want everything to be in Linux format.

https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4guide/Content/P4Guide/configuration.workspace.line-endings.html

If you want a particular file to always be submitted and synced bit-for-bit without any formatting awareness, use the `binary` filetype to specify that it should be interpreted as an opaque blob of binary instead of as a text file.

Comment: ok. thx. so I just have to right click on the workspace, maybe on edit,   and select unix line endings. ok I will try that . Thx for your answer

Comment: Make sure to set the `LineEnd` *before* you sync the files; it won't convert existing files in-place (but it will pick up the CRs when you submit)!  Do a "Remove from Workspace" before changing the setting and then "Get Latest" afterwards.

Comment: You might also like the `share` setting, which will strip CRs off CRLF files that your native Windows tools might produce.